# Multiple jQuery image/content sliders on a page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slideshow

I have two development sites, one is Wordpress, the other is not.

http://www.zimmernutrition.com.php53-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/ (Wordpress Site)

http://wtc.betaforming.com/communications/ (non Wordpress Site)

Both sites use the following for a content slider:

http://www.slidesjs.com/

Both sites use the following for an image slider:

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

On the site that isn't using WP, both sliders work.  On the WP site, the image slider (Found under the "Featured Products" heading) displays nothing.  Looking at the code, everything appears to be correct.

Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks

Brett

Comment: It's not working because...as the Console says, nivoSlider isn't a function at the time of the document ready. It might be because you are inserting the script into the element you're trying to call the slide against. Is there any reason you can't open up your themes header.php file and add the link in there?

Comment: Yes, it is working now!!  Thanks.  2 more questions...Why do you think it is working on the non-WP site?  The code is the same and placed the same way.  What's the Console?  Thanks again.  Brett

Comment: the Console is part of a JavaSript Debugger. IE9 has a built in Debugger, as does Chrome, press 'F12' to bring it up. Firefox requires an addon called Firebug, once again, 'F12' to bring it up. the Console logs information about errors in your page, and is also used for other debugging purposes. I don't think it worked on the WP site because the elements weren't ready at the time of DOM load. The way that WP pieces things together is in an synchronous fashion, as it reads into each individual file it loads the content. Basically, nivoSlider.js wasn't ready within that block when you called it.

Comment: Thanks for the Console help.  That all makes sense.